# Count unique Field it

Tags: count, report, unique, records

I have created a query with two tables (basic info) (trainings) joined with inner join and gives me data as below:

```
District   Department    Person      Trainings
Chitral    Health        ABC         Training 1
Chitral    Health        ABC         Training 2
Chitral    Health        DEF         Training 1
Chitral    Health        DEF         Training 3
Chitral    Health        DEF         Training 1
Chitral    Health        GHI         Training 4
```

On a report's District Header, i want to count unique Persons and count no of Trainings he received.

For example:  i want a text field that counts `Persons availed Trainings =3 and No of Trainings = 4`

Note: Few persons and few trainings are duplicates

Please guide me, how to get it right.

Comment: i tried simple count on person_id and training serial number (s_no)... it counts all person_id regardless of duplication.

Comment: Could you add the query in the OP and I'll see what I can do

Comment: @DieVeenman `SELECT qry_cdld_trainings_recieved.district, qry_cdld_trainings_recieved.dept, Count(qry_cdld_trainings_recieved.cbaid) AS CountOfcbaid, Count(qry_cdld_trainings_recieved.sno) AS CountOfsno
FROM qry_cdld_trainings_recieved
GROUP BY qry_cdld_trainings_recieved.district, qry_cdld_trainings_recieved.dept;
`